# Чем отличается обычная очередь от очереди головой и хвостом?

Tags: c++, указатели, список, очередь

Задали реализовать "очередь головой и хвостом" с помощью указателей в линейном списке и отсортировать методом пузырька, но нигде не могу найти объяснение: чем отличается обычная очередь от очереди головой и хвостом и как ее реализовать.

Comment: А Вы уточните у того, кто соорудил такое здание. Потому как очередь без головы и хвоста - это фигня, к элементам которой нет доступа, ни дать ни взять...

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, имеется в виду очередь в массиве, но построенная не на сдвиге, а на индексах начала и конца.

Например, очередь в массиве из 5 элементов - голова 0, хвост 0 - пусто. Добавляем элемент в очередь на место 0, хвост становится равен 1. Еще один элемент - и хвост равен 2. Забираем первый элемент из очереди - голова становится равна 1. Еще добавили два элемента - хвост стал равен 4. Забрали элемент - голова стала 2. Добавили еще один - и хвост должен бы стать 5, но становится 0 - циклически переходя в начало. Идея поняна?

Comment: Вообще-то в вопросе написано *`"с помощью указателей в линейном списке"`*